# Сортировка компонента catalog.section по массиву с нужными ID

Tags: битрикс

через Компонент search.page  выводятся все ID элементов которые в поиске были найдены, пишутся в массив $arElements получается массив вида

```
array(50) {
 [197819]=>
 string(7) "4495236"
 [204121]=>
 string(7) "4503644"
```

по этому массиву задается ключ в фильтре по ID

```
global $searchFilter;
$searchFilter = array(
"=ID" => $arElements,
"!CATALOG_PRICE_1"=>false,
);
```

И дальше catalog.section выводит нужные товары, но он сортирует не так, как стоят массивы после  search.page, я хочу отсортировать элементы в catalog.section через массив $arElements в котором ID идут в правильном порядке.
ставлю в параметрах  catalog.section

```
"ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "ID",
"ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => $arElements,
```

Он все равно не фильтрует

Answer (score 1):

В компоненте данную сортировку можно использовать с обновления 18.6.900 для iblock
Сортировка по массиву будет выглядеть в компоненте так:

```
"ELEMENT_SORT_FIELD" => "ID",
"ELEMENT_SORT_ORDER" => $arElements,
```

Получил ответ от Техподдержки 1с-bitrix спасибо!